# Como encriptar para um ficheiro .txt em Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um trabalho para fazer em que preciso de guardar dados de uma lista para ficheiros de texto.
Estes dados são maioritariamente, `password`, `username`, `idade`, `nacionalidade` e `numeroCC`. No trabalho é pedido que se guarde de forma encriptada **username;;password** num ficheiro de texto. Os restantes dados são guardados em ficheiros texto normais com tamanho fixo.

Explicando melhor, eu terei de criar 6 ficheiros, 3 deles para encriptação com pass e user de cada tipo de utilizador do programa que estou a realizar, com um organizador, vários membros da organização, e adeptos que usam a aplicação para comprar bilhetes, mas que para isso têm de estar registados. Os outros ficheiros vão ter tamanho fixo para guardar o resto dos dados.

Como posso fazer a parte da encriptação?

Eu já tentei fazer com o seguinte código para encriptar.

```
    private static byte[] key = new byte[10] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    private static byte[] iv = new byte[10] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    public static string encripta(string text)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = DES.Create();
        ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
        byte[] inputbuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] outputBuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputbuffer, 0, inputbuffer.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBuffer);
    }
```

Comment: Porque não utiliza MD5?

Comment: É possivel fazer isso? nunca trabalhei com isso :(  Vou ver se posso usar e se consigo implementar isso no código.

Comment: Sua pergunta é legal, mas não está clara o suficiente. Recomendo editar e explicar um pouco melhor o real problema e mostrar o que você já tentou. Assim ela irá passar pela revisão e pode ser reaberta.

Comment: Há formas mais eficientes de encriptar dados, mas usam XML. Veja mais [How to: Encrypt XML Elements with Symmetric Keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-encrypt-xml-elements-with-symmetric-keys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer a seguinte função:

**Encode**

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

**Decode**

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

E chamar a `Base64Encode` antes de salvar e chamar a `Base64Decode` quando for ler o dado.